# Swift : "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

so a general insight about what i am doing is implementing login and logout to facebook and retrieving the profile picture, name, id.

the login process and retrieving the information is working but my problem lies when i try to logout. i mainly have ExploreViewController which has the logout button, and the MeViewController is where the function that iam calling to set the label showing the information to something else

ExploreViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var LogoutButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func LogoutButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject!)

{
    let me = MeViewController()
    me.releseObjects()

}
```

iam successfully calling the IBAction

MeViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var idlable: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var firstName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var imgProfile: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()




    if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil)
    {
        let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"name,id,email"])
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in


            if ((error) != nil)
            {

            }
            else
            {

                let userName : NSString = result.valueForKey("name") as! NSString
                let userid : NSString = result.valueForKey("id") as! NSString
                self.firstName.text=userName as String
                self.idlable.text=userid as String


                let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
                let url = NSURL(string: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1&access_token="+accessToken)
                _ = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
                let data=NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

                    // Display the imag
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    self.imgProfile.image = image
            }
        })
    }


 func releseObjects(){

    let fn = "lolololol"

    self.firstName.text = fn //getting the error here
   }
```

iam successfully setting the firstName Label to the username that i get from Facebook in the viewDidLoad(), my problem is that i cant change the content of the label when i call the function releaseObjects()

Comment: check once `self.firstName` is connected through `IBOutlet` or not?

Comment: it is connected because i can successfully output the username in viewDidLoad after retrieving it from facebook

Comment: One of the implicit unwrapped values is `nil`. Set a breakpoint to check it

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new instance here `MeViewController` that is the reason of crash.

```
//ExploreViewController:
@IBOutlet weak var LogoutButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func LogoutButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject!)
{
    let me = MeViewController()
    me.releseObjects()
}
```

Better implement the `delegate/callbackHandler/Notification` Like.

```
//MeViewController
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "releseObjects", name: "Logout", object: nil)
}

func releseObjects(){
    self.firstName.text = "lolololol"  
}


ExploreViewController
@IBAction func LogoutButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject!){
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("Logout", object: nil)
}
```

Comment: i tried what you did in the releaseObjects() seems that its not entering the if statement because its actually nil, which doesn't make sense how can it be nil if i am assigning to it a string

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are creating a new instance of `MeViewController` from `ExploreViewController` and trying to call that `releseObjects` method:

```
let me = MeViewController()
me.releseObjects()
```

It's a new object, not the one that you were using previously. Since it is not presented, the outlets were not connected (It'll be nil). And when you try to access the `firstName` label it'll definitely crash.

I suggest you to re-use the actual object of `MeViewController`, instead of creating new one.